# How to login using webservices(Jersey) in java

Tags: java, mysql, web-services, jersey

How to login using webservices(JAX - RS) Jersey in java using database.Can anybody give suggestions for doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html) out. In this page check the CRUD RESTful webservice example. I guess that is what you need.